# angularjs integrate promise with resource

Tags: angularjs, promise, angular-resource

I have this resource:

```
myModule.factory('MyResource', ['$resource', 'geoLocationService', function ($resource, geoLocationService ) {

    return $resource('/blabla', {}, {
        'getData': { method: 'GET', params: { city: geoLocationService.getMyCity() } }
    });
}]);
```

The problem is that by the time of calling `MyResource.getData()`, geoLocationService haven't done to fetch the location.
geoLocationService has a promise which will allow me call

```
geoLocationService.promise.then(...)
```

But I don't know how I can integrate this promise with the resource. Any idea?

**EDIT**
I am looking for something like:

```
myModule.factory('MyResource', ['$resource', 'geoLocationService', function ($resource, geoLocationService ) {

    return $resource('/blabla', {}, {
        'getData': { method: 'GET', beforeFetchPromise: geoLocationService.promise, { city: geoLocationService.getMyCity() } }
    });
}]);
```

So only when geoLocationService.promise is resolved or rejected, the ajax call with parameters will occur.

Comment: Any update on this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add a promise in your controller:

```
$scope.resultsFromResource = YourResourceName.query().$promise.then(function(result){
    // code inside promise
})
```

I would also suggest that you either use query as in my example or remove single quotes around  your name getData if you want to keep that.

Comment: The geoLocationService() should work before the calling to resource and not after.